Seleniumbase Driver how to find an element inside of an element
Python Code
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(uc=True)

driver.open(URL)
element = driver.find_element("li[id^='marketItem']")
element_price = element.find_element(".rightCol")
print(element_price.text)
sleep(999)

I remember this working with undetected_chromedriver. But with Seleniumbase Driver I get the error:
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid locator

Is there another way to find the element of inside of an element ? Thanks in advance
Sorry for not including the entire error message.
Since I cant put in the entire message on here I uploaded it on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/GbnNAxvJ

Did the error happen on the first find_element() call?  On the second?  Somewhere else altogether?  Don't make us guess.  Post the full error traceback message.

@JohnGordon sorry about that. I edited the post and uploaded it on pastebin, since it wont let me add the entire thing on here

SeleniumBase's driver.find_element(selector) method autodetects the selector, which means you don't need to include the by when you call that method.
This is different from element.find_element(by, value), which comes from raw Selenium. There, you need to include the by, eg: by=By.CSS_SELECTOR.
In your case, you'd call element.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".rightCol") once you have the element, assuming you have from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By at the top.
